# how to update an input variable in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to update an input value based upon a user clicking a button. I have the following:

**html**

```
<input id="my-data-1" value="here is a value" />
<button data-which="my-data-1" class="update-form">update</button>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click','.update-form', function(){
    var me=$(this).attr('data-which');
   // this doesn't work, how would I update it?
    $("'#" + me + "'").val('something for you');  
  });
});
```

but it isn't working with error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '.update-form'

How would I make this work?

Comment: $('#' + me ).val('something for you'); Don't worry, JQuery will do the rest - selector will be recognized. No need for quotes.

Comment: ^^ thx @nevermind works good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').click(function(){
    var me=$('.update-form').attr('data-which');
    $('#' + me).val('something for you');  
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the single quotes on the line where you set the new value. You want:

```
$("#" + me).val('something for you');
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tchohoz2/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with how you are selecting the button, you could try a more guarenteed way to select it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').find('.update-form').on('click', function(){
        var me=$(this).attr('data-which');
        $("#" + me).val('something for you');  
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
$("#" + me).val('something for you');
});
```